# how to generate and store an RSA key (mod,public_exponent,private_exponent) in VBA?

Tags: vba

I want to implement a macro for RSA encryption of my own in VBA MS Word. So far so good, I implemented Miller-Rabin primality test to check if a number is primal or not, the problem is that according to a website: "http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#keylength" I must atleast provide a key length of 1024 bits in size, that's like 2^1024 in decimal which cleary no Type in VBA can hold. Even for the two random prime numbers that must be of length(Key)/2, 2^512 is still a long shot, How do I go about this ?

Comment: You have one mighty task in front of you. Even if you're able to generate the key you still have all the computations to do on very large numbers. Most people do this either with a `String` (eg "123456789") or `Byte Array` (eg b(0)=1, b(1)=2, etc.). I hope this isn't for true encryption as it'll be cracked in seconds ... and if you're just doing this for fun, then something like an Enigma emulator might be more fun and interesting for you to develop.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I figured that (in my class) we're just supposed to implement a simple RSA with a small key length ((sigh)) so I'll just stick with that and Long values because they're good for as long as a 2^31 -1 bits length. Again, I am sorry to have asked about implementing something so powerful on something like VBA.

Comment: Given that you have a few tough steps in front of you, not least writing a VBA solution for Euler's totient, then it makes sense to start with a data type that can manage the maths before you have to manipulate a String through that, and other, functions. Good luck with the project.